# MongoDB - how do I add a field to a nested object in one collection using a field from another collection?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation

I have two collections A and B.

Collection A has a nested object 'nested', which has a field 'id'.
Collection B also has a field 'id' and another 'type'.

My question is:

How can I add the 'type' field of collection B to collection A's nested object, where the id's match?

Comment: Are you trying to view the 'type' or do you want to store it inside Collection A?

Comment: Hi angrylemon, I'm trying to actually store it in collection A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, I was looking for a magic mongo one-liner query to do the job, but I think I'll tap out on that idea!

Finally, I used the following Java solution:

```
 private void updateNestedInCollectionAWithTypeFromCollectionBWhereIdsMatch(List<CollectionBPojo> collectionB, MongoCollection<Document> collectionA) {

    StreamUtils.createStreamFromIterator(collectionA.find().iterator()).forEach(d -> {
        final List<Document> nestedList = (List<Document>)d.get("nested");
        for (int i = 0; i < nestedList.size(); i++) {
            final Document nested = nestedList.get(i);
            if(!nested.containsKey("type")) {
                final String id = nested.getString("id");
                final Optional<CollectionBPojo> collectionBPojo = collectionB.stream().filter(g -> g.getId().equals(id)).findFirst();
                if (collectionBPojo.isPresent()) {
                    final String type = collectionBPojo.get().getType();                 
                    final Document query = new Document("id", d.get("id"));
                    final Document update = new Document();
                    update.append("$set", new BasicDBObject("nested" + "." + i + ".type", type));
                    updates.add(new UpdateOneModel<>(query, update));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if(!updates.isEmpty()) {
        final BulkWriteResult result = pipelineRunsCollection.bulkWrite(updates);         
    } else {
        System.out.print.ln("Nothing to update on db: " +  db.getName());
    }
}
```

}